# Flutter PopupMenuButton with dynamic items animation bug

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I tried to create a PopupMenuButton with a dynamic list of items like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:wideview/view_models/task_control_view_model.dart';
import 'package:wideview/widgets/gap.dart';

class TaskPopupMenuView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TaskPopupMenuView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final taskControlViewModel = ref.watch(taskControlViewModelProvider);
    List<Task>? tasks = taskControlViewModel.tasks;

    return PopupMenuButton<Task>(
      offset: const Offset(120, 50),
      // constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      //   maxHeight: 500,
      // ),
      icon: const TaskIcon(),
      onSelected: (item) => {
        if (item.isSelected)
          {
            ref.read(taskControlViewModelProvider.notifier).setNoSelectedTask(),
          }
        else
          {
            ref
                .read(taskControlViewModelProvider.notifier)
                .setSelectedTask(item),
          }
      },
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        // Build the list of PopupMenuItem dynamically based on tasks
        return tasks?.map((Task task) {
              return PopupMenuItem<Task>(
                value: task,
                child: TaskPopupView(task: task),
              );
            }).toList() ??
            [];
      },
      // itemBuilder: (context) => [
      //   PopupMenuItem<Task>(
      //       value: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask,
      //       child: TaskPopupView(task: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask!)),
      //   PopupMenuItem<Task>(
      //       value: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask,
      //       child: TaskPopupView(task: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask!)),
      //   PopupMenuItem<Task>(
      //       value: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask,
      //       child: TaskPopupView(task: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask!)),
      // ],
    );
  }
}
```

each item in the list displays a text the shows up with the open/close animation of the popup menu.
The problem is that this list is very long, and so, in order to constrain its length I add the commented field:

```
// constraints: const BoxConstraints(
//   maxHeight: 500,
// ),
```

This worked for the length problem but now when I open/close the menu, the item's animation isn't synced with the menu, the text just appears and disappears immediately.
Why is that? How can I fix it?

Note: when working with a non-dynamic list of items like so:

```
      // itemBuilder: (context) => [
      //   PopupMenuItem<Task>(
      //       value: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask,
      //       child: TaskPopupView(task: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask!)),
      //   PopupMenuItem<Task>(
      //       value: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask,
      //       child: TaskPopupView(task: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask!)),
      //   PopupMenuItem<Task>(
      //       value: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask,
      //       child: TaskPopupView(task: taskControlViewModel.selectedTask!)),
      // ],
```

this animation bug does not occur, and it works fine.

- I tried creating a custom PopupMenuButton, ended up with the same bug.
- I tried to give each item in the list its own animation (works for opening the menu, but not for closing it).
- I tried to wrap the PopUpMenuButton with a ContrainedBox widget like so:

```
ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: 500,
      ),
      child: PopupMenuButton<Task>(
```

didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

i see you are not synchronized with the appearance/disappearance of the dynamic items. you must have to use **ListView** and **ListView.builder** inside the **PopupMenuButton** check below code:

```
return PopupMenuButton<Task>(
  offset: const Offset(120, 50),
  icon: const TaskIcon(),
  onSelected: (item) {
    if (item.isSelected) {
      ref.read(taskControlViewModelProvider.notifier).setNoSelectedTask();
    } else {
      ref.read(taskControlViewModelProvider.notifier).setSelectedTask(item);
    }
  },
  itemBuilder: (context) {
    // Use List.generate to build the list of PopupMenuItem
    return List<PopupMenuEntry<Task>>.generate(
      tasks?.length ?? 0,
      (index) {
        final task = tasks![index];
        return PopupMenuItem<Task>(
          value: task,
          child: TaskPopupView(task: task),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

In this modified code, we use **List.generate** to generate a list of **PopupMenuItem** directly instead of using a ***ListView.builder***. This should resolve the error you mentioned.

Comment: This solution prompts the following error:

The return type 'ListView' isn't a 'List<PopupMenuEntry<Task>>', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: @NirPikan please check the updated answer and let me know if you are facing another issue.

Comment: Hey Noni, i tried using the updated answer but it results in the same outcome as my original code.
Using your solution, the list works fine but its length isn't restrained.
When trying to restrain its length by adding:

constraints: const BoxConstraints(
   maxHeight: 500,
 ),

to the PopupMenuButton, I get the same bug where the item's text appears before the animation finishes (the original issue).